# Submit form and call Ajax on <a> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to add something to database using Ajax. I have a link which submits the form and then Ajax call should work, but it's not. I use this same Ajax call on different page, but in that form I'm using simple button with type submit. But on this page, I want to submit with  ...

This is the form

```
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'ajax-form', 'style' => 'float:right']) !!}
  <input type="hidden" name = "idUser" id="idUser" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" name = "idCampaign" id="idCampaign" value="{{$campaign->id}}">
  <a class="fa fa-bookmark fa-2x" onclick="document.getElementById('ajax-form').submit();" aria-hidden="true" href="javascript:{}" style="color:#fd8809"></a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the Ajax:

```
$("#ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('addFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'failedd'){
              swal("Error!", "You have already added this campaign to favorites! If you want to remove it, go to your Favorites list page", "error")
            }
            else{
            swal("Success!", "You added the campaign "+ data.idCampaign + " to favorites!", "success")
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
            swal("Error!", "error")
        },
        complete: function (data) {
     }
    });
});
```

When I click on this link, it redirects me to another page which throws: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Comment: Post your routes.php (web.php when using Laravel 5.3+) file please.

Comment: `Route::post('addFavorites', 'SearchController@addFavorites');`

Comment: And what is the route of the actual page where you are being redirected to? And when you say you're being redirected, are you actually being redirected or it's just that the generated link simply takes you there?

Comment: It redirects me on the same page from where I click on this link `<a class="fa fa-bookmark fa-2x" onclick="document.getElementById('ajax-form').submit();" aria-hidden="true" href="javascript:{}" style="color:#fd8809"></a>`

Comment: Check out that there are no more routes with the name `'addFavorites'`.

Comment: Nope. There is only 1. Like I said, this Ajax works on another page from where I submit form using simple button. Here, this Ajax call is somehow ignored :/

Comment: Does the other page also belong to `SearchController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax url to this:

```
url: '/addFavorites',
```

and your route to this:

```
Route::post('/addFavorites', 'SearchController@addFavorites');
```

Just to make sure you point at the same url

> EDIT:

make sure that you have one route with **get** and the same route with **post**. see bellow:

Route::get('/addFavorites', 'SearchController@loadFavorites'); *<-to load the page*

Route::post('/addFavorites', 'SearchController@submitFavorites'); *<-to submit the data*

1. Change this: `$("#ajax-form").submit(function(event) {`

   To this: `$('#yourid').click(function(){`
2. Remove the onclick in the 'a' element and add the `id='yourid'` with the name you want.

Comment: The route is ok. It works when I remove <a> and submit the form with simple `<input type="submit">`

Comment: In what page you get redirected?

Comment: I stay on the same page. Ajax just calls addFavorites function and inserts in db.

Comment: With the <a> element you said that you get redirected to another page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake! I am redirected to the same page, but with a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Answer (score 0):

MethodNotAllowedHttpException usually comes when you haven't defined route or you have defined route for get method and you are using the route for post method. please check your routes.php

Comment: that means event.preventDefault(); is not working properly